# How do i get sonarqube issues with a git commit?

Tags: git, sonarqube

I have being trying to get details of a project being analysed with sonarqube's api, which went fine. Now i the situation is different as, for example a user commits to git with some issues, and i should be able to get the sonarqube issues from the git commit id. I need help linking the git commit to sonarqube's analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct search for that. You will have to integrate Jenkins into it.